# Geometry Type error preventing saving of layer after editing - geometry type is correct under layer information

Tags: qgis, geometry, editing, error, linestring

I have a problem with a linestring layer that doesn't want to be saved after editing.

The layer itself shows 'LineString' under the information tab. When I add a line with the tool by snapping the line along some points, it doesn't let me save the layer. I get the error 'geometry type not compatible with the current layer'. I checked the points to see if they are 3D, but they are not according to the information tab.

I have uploaded a line that comes up in the 'check geometries' as invalid geo type to this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IBVQtoAp_hkDYvLmcMabbnA67CMHTkQC/view?usp=sharing).
This one line also shows 'LineString' under the information tab.

Has anybody seen this before and has a solution? I thought I had found a workaround by just exporting the layer in editing mode, but it destroys, I think, the invalid lines in random ways. For example cuts them in weird places, and in random places.

I do have to note that not too long ago the information tab would tell me a wrong geometry type, not sure why.

I'm on a Windows 10 machine with the LTR Hannover QGIS.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but when I loaded this up in QGIS, I saw something funky. The geometry **isn't** coded as a `LineString` - instead, it's coded as a `MultiCurve`. Here is the WKT data for that geometry: `MultiCurve (LineString (532269.44620930461678654 6064100.59224237687885761, 532256.41602105519268662 6064093.993363325484097))`. That might be the reason why you're having a hard time manipulating it.

Comment: Ok, that is weird. I made the line in question with the line tool. How did you find out it is a multicurve? And apparently over 80% of the lines I created are not linestrings. Any idea how to convert them? Drawing them again results in the same issue not for all but for others again.

Comment: You can investigate the geometry type of each row (one-by-one) by installing the "Get WKT" plugin in QGIS. To investigate them all at once, you'll need to export the layer as a CSV. In the "Save Vector Layer as..." window, under "Geometry", select "LineString" and under "Layer Options", choose the "AS_WKT" option for "Geometry".

Comment: The annoying thing here is that I cannot think about a way to truly solve this inside QGIS. I think you might just need to use the exported CSV and use some other tool (e.g.: some Python script) to convert the geometries from MultiCurve to LineString (or, at most, MultiLineString).

Comment: Thank you for explaining the WKT. I had a related issue a few weeks ago where qgis showed linestring as geometry but there were multilines. Could this be a similar "bug"?

Comment: How does one create multicurves in qgis? In case it is a user error, so I can avoid it.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! And regarding how to avoid making MultiCurves, well... I sadly have absolutely no idea, hahahahaha... Sorry for not having a better answer here.